# React Navigation 6 - Header Title moves to opposite direction as Screen. Why?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I changed the direction the screen moves to move from left to right. However, while the screen moves from left-right, the header title moves still from right to left which looks of course weird. Is there a way to make the header also move from left to right?

```
 <Stack.Screen
      name="Tabs"
      options={({navigation,route}) => ({
         headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle,
         headerShown: false,
      })}>
          {(props) => <MyTabs {...props} />}
</Stack.Screen>
<Stack.Screen
    name="Settings"
    component={SettingsScreen}
    options={{
        headerTitle: 'Settings',
        headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle,
        headerShown: true,
        gestureDirection: 'horizontal-inverted',
        headerLeft: () => <BackButton />
    }}
/>
</Stack.Navigator>

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

...
<Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={{
       headerTitleStyle: styles.headerTitleStyle,
       headerShown: true,
    }}
/>
...
```

Comment: Can you post the definition of ```headerTitleStyle```

Comment: there is nothing important - only fontSize and fontFamily.

Comment: The header just perform an crossfade (sample: https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/stack-navigator-header-naimation)

Comment: thank you. I am navigating to the settings screen from my Home screen which is a nested tab (not stack) navigator so Im not sure how to add the transitions there. I edited my question with the tabnavigatior

Comment: What do you mean by nested tab ? You have a tabgroup within another tabgroup ?

Comment: my tab navigator (to which Home belongs to, from which I navigate to my Settings) is nested in my stack navigator (please see edited code). I dont know where I would add  ...TransitionPresets.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS, since Home is not a stack but a Tab

Answer (score 0):

Simple add in options  headerMode: 'screen'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).